# Find rook polynomial for a full $n\times n$ board

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Alan Tucker's Applied Combinatorics question. I have a full $n \times n$ board and I need to find the rook polynomial. I am not sure if I comprehend the method wrong, but I am approaching this inductively, so I looked at a $2\times 2$ board (it's full so I'm assuming each square is shaded and I can place it in any way) so
the polynomial I got for a $2\times 2$ board is $$ 1 + 4x + 4x^{2}.$$
Then for a $3\times 3$ board, I got $$ 1 + 9x + 12x^{2} + 22x^{3}.$$

However, I saw as comment on another question that my polynomial for 3x3 might be incorrect...

Anyway for a $4\times 4$ board, I'm at $$ 1 + 16x + 24x^{2} +...$$

Am I sort of on the right track as to how I would find the rook polynomial for a full nxn board?

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_polynomial) and its references.

Comment: I see wikipedia, but I still don't see where this summation/relationship comes from for each of the rook polynomials, for example, why is it that for $$ x^{3} $$ when n=3, its $$ 6x^{3} $$ , but for n=4 it is $$ 96x^{3} $$ ?

Comment: For $n=2$, it should be $1+4x+2x^2$, and the others are wrong as well. If you can explain why you got $1+4x+4x^2$, we can help you fix your method.

Comment: I got 4 for $$ x^{2} $$ because I thought that in a 2 x 2 board, there were 4 ways to place a rook as in... I thought that because it was corresponding to the square term I needed to see how to place blocks of two on the board so, I counted 2 horizontal and 2 vertical?

Comment: @JocelineNatali For the $x^2$ term in the 2x2 board you should be counting the number of ways to place 2 non-attacking rooks on that 2x2 board (meaning these two chess rooks cannot be in the same row or column). How many ways can do you do that? (Hint: diagonals)

Comment: Ohh, I see it has to be nonattacking rooks. So just the two ways the diagonal going from top left to bottom right, and bottom left to bottom right. However, I still don't quite see the relationship for n > 4. Like what is the equation for placing 3 nonattacking rooks?